# Dynamically build the Ajax.ActionLink , with current controller name, action method name and the current parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I added the following to my general view:-

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(Model.FirstOrDefault().ServerID.ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString(),null)
```

But I need the above Ajax.ActionLink to get the current URL parameters and override it .
As this view is general , so it will be displayed from different URLs, such as :-

```
/Customer/CustomerVM?customerID=11701&page=2
/Server/ServerVM/341?page=2
```

So i want the Actionlink to override the current parameters by adding the filter name

so  the URL paramertes `“customerID=11701&page=2”` should be `“customerID=11701&page=2&filter=server”` .And `“/341?page=2”` should be `“/341?page=2&filter=server”`.
So I am not sure if there is a way to get the current parameters URL and override them ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try with : @HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["yourParameter"]